# Why does JSON.stringify(new Error('huh') ) not include the error message field

Tags: javascript, node.js

In NodeJS (same applies to Javascript in browser), **why doesn't `JSON.stringify(new Error('huh'))` print out the Error.message property?**

I was debugging some NodeJS code dealing with a file open error and used `JSON.stringify()` to the Error object, and was surprised when I didn't see the message property.

See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#class-error for a list of the fields that include:

- error.code
- error.message
- error.stack

To illustrate, copy the following line into your browser console, or run it as a NodeJS file.

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(new Error('huh')));
// output is: {}
```

But the field is there as shown by the following lines of code that display the message field.

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(new Error('huh'))); // {}
console.log((new Error('huh')).toString());    // Error: huh
console.log((new Error('huh')).message);       // huh
```

I'm not sure what to search for to find this answer.

SO had the following but they were unrelated to my question:

- [Get JSON.stringify error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669810/get-json-stringify-error-message)
- [Why the error message do not appear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902843/why-the-error-message-do-not-appear)

For completeness, the MDN (browser) Error object is documented here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

### UPDATE

This question was (rightfully) closed as a duplicate of [Is it not possible to stringify an Error using JSON.stringify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391212/is-it-not-possible-to-stringify-an-error-using-json-stringify).

The short answer to the question is:

The Error class doesn't have ".toJSON" method and the JSON.stringify() method's default way of obtaining properties to process does not include the `message` field because the message field is not marked as enumerable

```
Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(new Error('huh'), 'message').enumerable
// returns false
```

Credit to @bogdanoff, ASDFGerte and @Jonathan Lonowski (for the duplicate answer)

To get all of the fields of the Error object you can use the following:

```js
let err = new Error('huh');
console.log('stringify: ' + JSON.stringify(err, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(err)));
```

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

Comment: `Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(new Error('huh'), 'message').enumerable`

Comment: ```JSON.stringify({ name: err.name, message: err.message })``` ?

Comment: What search terms did you use? The second SO question you link is entirely unrelated, it's [tag:php].

Comment: Error class doesn't have ".toJSON" method that's why.

Comment: @Bergi, the SO questions I listed were in the suggestions that SO offers when you are writing the question.  I didn't know what to search for an answer for this question.

Comment: @bogdanoff, this is the answer I was looking for.  Thank you!  I never (till now) knew that stringify() used the toJSON() function on objects.  Found https://thecodebarbarian.com/what-is-the-tojson-function-in-javascript.html that explained it!  I wish you could open the question and answer it.

Comment: @ASDFGerte, I didn't realize till I studied what `enumerable` is that I realized you were giving me the answer.   Because the `message`  field is not enumerable, it doesn't show up in the `JSON.stringify()` output.